# Ubuntu touchegg won't start on startup using /etc/rc.local

Tags: ubuntu, startup, nohup

I can run touchegg successfully by `sh /etc/rc.local` but it won't automatically start on startup.

contents of my rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log
nohup touchegg &
exit 0
```

rc.local logs on startup:

```
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
touchegg: cannot connect to X server
```

I'm running ubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: It's trying to start, but can't connect to X Window. Is that running? Does it allow connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this post but I found the solution I just needed to wait a little bit for lubuntu to initialize X server. I just added sleep at the beginning.